# Attempting to get a Hex grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid, hex, tiles

Im trying to get the hex prefab shapes that have already been created to line up with one another in a grid formation. I got the grid but I can't seem to get the hexes to fit into each other. Fixed the y%2 but the way it is setup now it crashes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class boardObject : MonoBehaviour {

// Instantiates a prefab in a grid

public GameObject prefab;
public float gridX = 5f;
public float gridY = 5f;
public float spacing = 2f;

void Start() {
    for (float y = 0.0f; y < gridY; y++) {
        for (float x = 0.0f; x < gridX; x++) {
            // THIS IS WHAT WAS MISSING FOR THIS TO ACTUALLY WORK MAKING A NEW VECTOR 3
            // POSITION AFTER THE LOOP WAS SET UP. EACH NEW hex NEEDED HAVE A NEW POSITION. ->
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, 0.0f, y) * spacing;
            //
            //
            //%2 thingy
            if (y%2.0f==0.0f)
                gridY += 0.5f;
            else 
                gridY -= 0.0f;
            Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);


        }
    }

}
```

}

First pic is the one I have, second is the one I am trying to make.
[This is the square board hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIV4p.png)

[This is what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKR2F.jpg)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `y%0` isn't useful.  Do you mean `y%2`?

Comment: Thank you i fixed that, but it still does not work.

Comment: My guess is that the horizontal spacing isn't the same as the vertical?  This is because hexagons have a different width than height (compared to squares) so you'd have to multiply your `x` and `y` values by different amounts instead of multiplying the whole vector (which is a confusing thing to do anyway).

Comment: I think I understand what your saying but I don't know how I would do that for each odd line of hexes. in order to get the peaks to go into the valleys. The grid itself is good if they where squares.

Comment: `Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x*1.75, 0.0f, y*2);` Where the 1.75 value is made up (you'll have to play with it).  The "odd" lines are irrelevant.  If line 2 moves over, then line 3 needs to move over that much too....plus some more so it nestles in close, which means line 4 needs to move...and so on.  My point was: you're treating them like squares and they're *not* squares: their bounding boxes are rectangular.

Comment: What you are saying makes since but it still creates the same grid. Multiplying x and y only increases the space between lines of hexes.

Comment: Then I do not understand the problem.  Please include an image indicating what you wish to change.

Comment: Added pictures if that helps.

Comment: Ahh, I thought you'd already worked out that problem, but were having incorrect spacing.  Now it gets complicated.  First thing's first: how do you want your grid to line up?  Do you want the hexes oriented how you have them (the edge parallel to the screen being vertical) or another orientation?  It might not seem like it makes a difference, but it will when you come to working out the math.  For example, this ( http://s18.postimg.org/60gq5xuop/hex1.png ) will be easier to calculate than this ( http://s27.postimg.org/al7q8k23n/hex2.png ). Horizontal vs. vertical being irrelevant.

Comment: The easiest way to calculate.

Comment: Alright then.  Start by rewriting your function so that the flat edges line up on a single row (or column).  e.g. make one of your loops only go up to 1.  Once that is making a single row (or column) with flat edges aligning with flat edges (rather than points, as your columns do currently) you can make the second line position correctly.

Comment: I changed this "for (float x = 1; x < gridX; x++) {" x to 1 instead of 0 and it seems to have worked. Let me figure out the spacing, if that was it that is very annoying because I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: and that was it, now it works thank you.

Comment: It always helps to reduce the problem to its simplest. In this case, a 1-by-N structure.  Once that works, do 2-by-N.  Finally you can expand to an X-by-N.

Comment: Yea that doesnt really make much since to me do you have a link to a resource to learn more about the x by n things?

Comment: No, its not a resource I can point you to, its just a way of reducing the problem to a simpler one.  In this case I already knew how to represent a hexagonal grid as a square one.  In so doing I knew that the simplest possible grid was a 1x1 grid (a single hex).  To get bigger I end up with a 1x2 to which there is only 1 possible solution (irrespective of orientation).  Bigger means tacking on more hexes in a line, ergo: drawing a single row is the first point at which I can verify that I am doing things correctly.

Comment: Oh ok well thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class boardObject : MonoBehaviour {

// Instantiates a prefab in a grid

public GameObject prefab;
public float gridX = 5f;
public float gridY = 5f;
public float spacing = 2f;
public float xsize = 1.0f;
public float ysize = 1.0f;

void Start() {
    for (float y = 0; y < gridY; y++) {
        for (float x = 1; x < gridX; x++) { //<<<<<This is where the change was made to get it to work. x = 1 instead of 0.


            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (x * xsize, 0.0f, y * ysize) ;

            Instantiate (prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);


            if (y % 2 == 0)
                y += 1;
            else 
                y -= 1;

        }
    }

}
void Update() {
```

}
    }